# Closing settings programmatically

Tags: java, android, settings

I need some help , I tram trying to close android settings, (com.android.settings (packageName)), but I can't find how can it be done, I am testing in android O , please suggest something , I tried to kill process but it did'nt work too .. 
how can it be done ?  )

Comment: I would not assume that the Settings app has the same package name across all Android device models.

Comment: @CommonsWare , no matter has the same or not , only i want to kill setting or remove from recent activities when i start my activity , how can it be done ?)

Comment: @ant_dev you found  a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, you can read more about it in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Here is an example

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YOUR_ACTIVIRTY.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: thank you for suggest , I tried it , , I want to kill it ,but it still exists) ,,  I want to close Android settings !! and nothing helps me do do it )) I am in trouble ))))

Comment: When you open your settings, you make some treatments in onActivityResult() right? Why don't you try to reload your Activity there ?